# 'Collection was modified' error when Deleting Related Entities

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am trying to delete some items using Entity Framework. I want to delete those items with `DestinationId` that is not in `int[] destinationIds`. (I am deleting rows in a junction table.)

```
foreach (var destination in product.ImportedProductDestinations.Where(ipd => !destinationIds.Contains(ipd.DestinationId)))
    product.ImportedProductDestinations.Remove(destination);
```

But the `foreach` statement gives me the run-time error:

> Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

Alright, I think I understand this error. But how else can I do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

do not remove the item from the collection you are scanning, delete it from the db context

```
context.IMportedProductDestinations.DeleteObject(destination);
```

and then apply the changes to the db using context.SaveChanges

Comment: Since I could use `ToList()` as Habib suggested, why is this approach better?

Comment: I have not analyzed to determine which method is better, perhaps you could do that. I have found it more efficient to update the context with the changes I need and then save those changes.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the exception because, You are trying to iterate a collection using `foreach` and deleting an item from it. You can add `ToList` to your `product.ImportedProductDestinations.Where(ipd => !destinationIds.Contains(ipd.DestinationId))` and then remove the item.

```
foreach (var destination in product.ImportedProductDestinations
                                   .Where(ipd => !destinationIds.Contains(ipd.DestinationId))
                                   .ToList())
{
    product.ImportedProductDestinations.Remove(destination);
}
```

Comment: This is probably the best, but does .NET store the value of the List the first time or reevaluate it each time? If it doesn't then OP might run into the same problem.. unless of course it is all down to how  an IEnumerable iterates..

Answer (score 1):

You cannot remove an item from a collection as you are iterating over it in a foreach.

```
var result = product.ImportedProductDestinations.Where(ipd => !destinationIds.Contains(ipd.DestinationId)).ToList());

    For(int i= 0;i<result.count();i++)
    (
       product.ImportedProductDestinations.Remove(result[i]);
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a remove list:

```
 foreach (var destination in product.ImportedProductDestinations.Where(ipd => !destinationIds.Contains(ipd.DestinationId)))
     ListRemove.Add(ipd.DestinationId)

foreach (var remove in  ListRemove)
product.ImportedProductDestinations.Remove(remove)
```